# PHP Associate array populated by form input

Tags: php, arrays

I need to populate an associative array from a form input. Each time the user clicks submit it runs the PHP script, then it redirects them back to the form in which they can add another key value pair to the array.

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" name="form-one">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php
    //Add input vales to associative array dynamically
?>
```

So each time the form gets processed, I need the name and id saved in a key value pair, adding on the previous one that was saved.

Comment: the magic word here is AJAX

Comment: Where / how are you storing the data?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390042/my-array-values-keep-dissapearing-and-refreshing-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that will be a bit trickier, as a php script is executed every time a form is passed and then terminated. What you could do is persist the previous data somewhere, to a database, or serialize it to a file, then simply read the file on execution, and then append your newest entry on top of that.

Another way of going about it is by using sessions. You could store the array in a session variable e.g. `$_SESSION['array']`, and simply append to that each time your form gets processed.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a good solution, can't you directly work with the data that gets submitted? In your procss you would have to put the values into the session, that makes the handling unnecessary troublesome later on.

```
if(isset($_POST['form-one'])){
     $_SESSION[formData[$_POST['id']]] = $_POST['name'];
}
```

This would put the array formdata in your session-array, the id becomes index and name the value.

Comment: I get an error 
    PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']' in your code